# Matlab from text file to sparse matrix.

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files, sparse-matrix

I have a huge text file in the following format:

```
1   2
1   3
1   10
1   11
1   20
1   376
1   665255
2   4
2   126
2   134
2   242
2   247
```

First column is the `x` coordinate while second column is the `y` coordinate.
It indicates that if I had to construct a Matrix

```
M = zeros(N, N);
M(1, 2) = 1;
M(1, 3) = 1;
.
.
M(2, 247) = 1;
```

This text file is huge and can't be brought to main memory at once. I must read it line by line. And save it in a **sparse matrix**.

So I need the following function:

```
function mat = generate( path )
    fid = fopen(path);
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    % initialize an empty sparse matrix. (I know I assigned Mat(1, 1) = 1)
    mat = sparse(1);
    while ischar(tline)
        tline = fgetl(fid);
        if ischar(tline)
            C = strsplit(tline);
        end
        mat(C{1}, C{2}) = 1;
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

But unfortunately besides the first row it just puts trash in my sparse mat.
Demo:

```
1 7
1 9
2 4
2 9
```

If I print the sparse mat I get:

```
   (1,1)        1
  (50,52)       1
  (49,57)       1
  (50,57)       1
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to convert `C{1}` and `C{2}` to numbers with `str2double()`. However if the file of coordinates is too big for main memory, then it's most likely the sparse array you're trying to construct will be too big also. I believe that MATLAB uses a compressed sparse column representation internally which will be bigger than a set of co'ordinate pairs...

Comment: @Justin I am sorry. It is 500MB, what I meant is I cant open it in a normal matrix and then make it sparse as it will be too big. I need to construct the sparse by taking lines.

Comment: @TonyTannous: One minor suggestion: since `path` is a built-in function, you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @gnovice thanks for answer & suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing what you have...

Your problem is that `C` is a cell array [*of characters*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html), not numbers. You need to convert the strings you read from the file into integer values. Instead of [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) you can use functions like [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html). Since `tline` is a space-delimited character array of integers in this case, `str2num` is the easiest to use to compute `C`:

```
C = str2num(tline);
```

Then you just index `C` like an array instead of a cell array:

```
mat(C(1), C(2)) = 1;
```

*Extra tidbit:* If you were wondering how your demo code still worked even though `C` contained characters, it's because MATLAB has a tendency to automatically convert variables to the correct type for certain operations. In this case, the characters were converted to their [double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) ASCII code equivalents: `'1'` became `49`, `'2'` became `50`, etc. Then it used these as indices into `mat`.

### A simpler alternative...

You don't even have to bother with all that mess above, since you can replace your entire function with a much simpler approach using [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) and [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) like so:

```
data = dlmread(filePath);
mat = sparse(data(:, 1), data(:, 2), 1);
clear data;  % Save yourself some memory if you don't need it any more
```

Comment: btw [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) uses [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) for conversion. You might want to use [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) instead

Comment: @SardarUsama: That won't work on a string of space-delimited numbers, though. For example, `str2double('1 2 3')` gives `NaN`.

Comment: How about using it with `strsplit`? if `a='1 2 3 4'` ;  then `str2double(strsplit(a))`

Comment: Not working on big files :( `ones` explodes in memory.

Comment: @TonyTannous: I removed the dependence on `ones` and added a call to clear, but even still the fact that you were having memory errors with just that leads me to think you must have so many rows of data that any calculations you try to do down the line are going to give you memory errors as well, even using a sparse matrix.